# Entity Manager Not Returning Column Names

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

i'm querying a table through entity manager, it returns a resultList but it only returns the values and not the column names (ss attached) which is obvious because I am not providing the  Entity class to map the result to. i can not provide the exact entity class as the scenario i'm dealing with is dynamic and i do not know what entity will be returned in the resultSet which is why i have only provided a parent class which is not a mapped entity. however i do know that the entity will contain a specific columns and they are known. is there a way i can map this resultSet to a class on modify it to return the column names as well?

```
Query emQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query.toString());
        List<MasterDataSource> objectList = emQuery.getResultList();
```

here are the contents of the list returned which shows that it's not returning the name rather values only.

[image]

Parent class is below

[image]

Comment: Please add code as text not as screenshot. How your query looks like?

Comment: It isn't possible to get the column names in the resultset. But you should know the columns, because they are part of the query

Comment: my query is just a select * from <table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, use `@SqlResultSetMapping` and provide the column names and types.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="datasourceResult", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = MasterDataSource.class,
                columns = {@ColumnResult(name="id", type = Long.class), @ColumnResult(name="data", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name="account_id", type = String.class),@ColumnResult(name="data_type", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name="create_datetime", type = String.class),@ColumnResult(name="data_interface", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name="record_seq_no", type = Integer.class),@ColumnResult(name="source_file_name", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name="source_file_path", type = String.class),@ColumnResult(name="destination", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name="is_processed", type = Boolean.class)})
})
```

this requires a constructor for all above fields since I am using `@ConstructorResult`

usage:
use the name of the of the `@SqlResultSetMapping` in your createNativeQuery call

```
Query emQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query.toString(), "datasourceResult");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<yourType> objectList = emQuery.getResultList();
```